# Why SSIS Script is losing NuGet package and references after I close and reopen the script?

Tags: ssis, nuget-package-restore, csvhelper, script-task, microsoft.bcl

I have written a script in SSIS script task editor to read csv files using CsvHelper. While executing the package it is throwing the following error:

> 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.' >

[image: error]

I have removed and reinstalled and even tried updating the packages (`Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode`, `System.Memory`) for the references with warning signs (yellow triangles) on reference list (image). For the time being, it gets fixed but when I close the script and try to execute the package or open the script editor again it returns to the previous state.

NB: I am using SSIS 2017, target framework 4.7

I would be thankful for any workaround suggestions.

[image: reference list]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the text file connector? Creating scripts in SSIS makes things complicated. Using external libraries makes it even more complicated. Try your best to use out of the box tools first.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually the package itself is complicated. These files will be dynamic based on the user upload. Then it needs to read the rows and columns, map with the existing table and insert.

Comment: In my opinion, SSIS is the wrong tool for this. You can bash it to make it work for dynamic files, but you're better off using a different tool - I usually drop back to powershell if there is a complex requirement.